How do I set up different license types for an appexchange product at different prices
We are launching an appExchange app and want to have two types of licenses with different prices.
Type 1 license = Full Access @ $30 per user per month (an example)
Type 2 license = Limited Access @ $10 per user per month
Type 1 can access all the features and objects in the app
Type 2 can only access certain custom objects and features in the app
How do you set this up?  Is it via the permissions within a package and/or in the License Management App (LMA) or via a different method?
Also, how do the different license types get displayed in the AppExchange listing when a user goes to buy the licenses?
There is another blog post similar to this about the same topic but in my opinion that didn't answer the question fully.  We prefer not to create two packages because it's not the best experience from a user standpoint.  And the other option mentioned in the other post called "Licensing Component" is not available yet.  I'm also not clear how licensed permission sets work which was another option to solving this, so if someone can clarify, that would be appreciated. I understand permission sets but how are "licensed" permission sets different and how do you set that up?
Thanks in advance!

This question is similar to: Do I have options on creating multiple license types for a single app published on AppExchange?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
